# XSD extension to enable any element containing particular node

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML and an XSD scheme for it, currently the validation works fine!
Now in some particular cases I would like to enable any XML element to contain particular node.

E.g. for given XML

```
<Root>
   <Element1 Name="test1>Text1</Element1>
   <Element2 Name="test2>
   </Element2>
</Root>
```

I would like to extend XSD so that any element could contain node
text.

e.g.

```
<Root>
   <Template>element within Root</Template> 
   <Element1 Name="test1>Text1<Template>element inline</Template></Element1>
   <Element2 Name="test2>
      <Template>element within Element2</Template> 
   </Element2>
</Root>
```

I would really appreciate any help!

BR

Comment: When you say "contain node text" you mean "contain character data as well as child elements"?  Or "contain a Template element"? or what?  Question doesn't seem clear.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it was not expressed clear enough. 

The idea was to add a node <Template>TEXT HERE</Template> anywhere

Answer (score 0):

In XSD 1.0 its difficult to do this, you need to place <xs:any> elements where you want the 'any' elements to appear.

However its not that simple, placing an <xs:any> in the wrong place creates ambiguity (and is not allowed), and this will cover almost everywhere you want to put them!

In XSD 1.1 you can use openContent ([brief tutorial](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Reference/XmlStudio/XsdEditorNotation_OpenContent.html)), but again there are issues, XSD 1.1 is not supported natively in .Net, but if your working in java then the Xerces supports XSD 1.1 (at least a beta version was available last time i looked).